# (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading - cutom service

Tags: angular

Hello as part of Angular 2 learning project I am creating a test app.

I am trying to eagerly load one of the Module called `LoginModule`, however, I get the following error:

> Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/app/core.js Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/app/core.js at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1039:29) [] at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:47) [ => ] at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:345:33) [] Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/core.js as "../core" from http://localhost:3000/app/login/login.service.js at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1039:29) [] at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:47) [ => ] at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:345:33) [] Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/core.js as "../core" from http://localhost:3000/app/login/login.service.js at addToError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:122:78) [] at linkSetFailed (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:695:21) [] at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:495:9 [] at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:113:43) [ => ] at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:535:57 [] at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:47) [ => ] at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:433:35) [] at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:349:25) []

I tried to refer other questions where error message is similar to above however nothing has helped me yet.

It would be great if someone could help me solve the issue.

My directory structure is as follows:

[image]

**login-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(routes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ],
})
export class LoginRoutingModule{ }

export const loginRoutableComponents = [
    LoginComponent
];
```

**login.module.ts** looks like this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


import { UserProfileService } from './user-profile.service';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';
import { LoginRoutingModule, loginRoutableComponents } from './login-routing.module';



@NgModule({
    imports: [ CommonModule,
            LoginRoutingModule ],
    declarations: [ loginRoutableComponents ],
    providers: [ LoginService, UserProfileService ]
})
export class LoginModule{ }
```

**login.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';

import { SpinnerService } from '../core';
import { UserProfileService } from './user-profile.service';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    constructor(
        private userProfileService: UserProfileService,
        private spinnerService: SpinnerService){}

    login(){
        return Observable.of(true)
                .do(_ => this.spinnerService.show())
                .delay(1000)
                .do(this.toggleLoginState.bind(this));
    }

    logout(){
        this.toggleLoginState(false);
    }

    private toggleLoginState(val: boolean){
        this.userProfileService.isLoggedIn = val;
        this.spinnerService.hide();
    }
}
```

**user-profile.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UserProfileService{
    isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import { LoginService } from './login.service';
import { UserProfileService } from './user-profile.service';
import { ToastService } from '../core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    // selector: 'login',
    // templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
    template: `
                <div>  
                    <h5>Login component</h5>
                    <div>
                        <button id='login-button' *ngIf='!isLoggedIn' (click)='login()'>Login</button>
                        <button id='logout-button' *ngIf='isLoggedIn' (click)='logout()'>Logout</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                `
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy { 
    loginSub: Subscription;

    public get isLoggedIn(){
        return this.userProfileService.isLoggedIn;
    }

    constructor(
        private loginService: LoginService,
        private toastService: ToastService,
        private userProfileService: UserProfileService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router
    ){}
    ngOnInit() {
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.loginSub.unsubscribe();
    }

    login(){
        this.loginSub = this.loginService
                            .login()
                            .mergeMap( (loginResult) => this.route.queryParams )
                            .map(qp => qp['redirectTo'])
                            .subscribe(redirectTo => {
                                this.toastService.activate('Logged in sucessessfully.');
                                let url = redirectTo? redirectTo : ['characters'];
                                this.router.navigate(url);
                            });
    }
    logout(){
        this.loginService.logout();        
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like a problem with your System JS config. The problem is because you are trying to use a barrel (index). Barrels aren't naturally supported with SystemJS. You need to configure the barrels you are using or just use `from '../core/index'` where you specify the barrel. See https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/1301

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks. This thing was never discussed in the course I am going through. Thanks pointing me to the discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@peeskillet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2587435/peeskillet)
I found answer to this problem.

I am using [barrels](http://tattoocoder.com/angular2-barrels/) to reduce no of import statements required to import various components from a bunch of [feature modules](https://johnpapa.net/introducing-angular-modules-feature-modules-2/). As mentioned by peeskillet in his comment above, barrels are not naturally supported by SystemJS. It needs to be either configured in System.config.js or while using import statements one has to provide name of the barrel file for example in login.service.ts I have replaced

```
import { SpinnerService } from '../core';
```

to

```
import { SpinnerService } from '../core/index';
```

and voila suddenly the error mentioned in question disappeared :)